# Flash 4 BitmapImage and events

Tags: flash, events, apache-flex, bitmapimage, flex-spark

I am trying to use BitmapImage spark class instead of mx image class.
Image loads the same, fine

```
<s:BitmapImage  id="img" source="sample.jpg">

</s:BitmapImage>
```

But I have an issue with adding mouse events on it, eg:

```
img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicked);
```

do not trigger any mouse events when clicking on the image

Help!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, handling the events through the Graphic class ...

```
<s:Graphic id="img">


        <s:BitmapImage   source="media/paxRomana005_150dpi.jpg">

        </s:BitmapImage>
</s:Graphic>
```

Who can light me ...? Thanks

Comment: The BitmapImage class is a lightweight class for displaying images. It doesn't contain any code for handling interaction. If you would like it to be interactive (listen for click events) then you can do what you're doing or use an s:Image component.